# In Javascript, why is the minimum of an empty spread array Infinity?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'm using a generator to create objects, like so:

```js
function* Thing() {
  var x = 0;
  while (x < 3) {
    var rules = [{arr: [1, 2, 3]}, {arr: [1]}, {arr: []}];
    yield {
      arrayMinimum: Math.min(...rules[x].arr)
    }
    x++
  }
}

var create = Thing();

console.log(create.next().value)
console.log(create.next().value)
console.log(create.next().value) // { arrayMinimum: Infinity } ???
```

Why is `Math.min(...[]) === Infinity`?

Bonus confusion: `Math.max(...[]) === -Infinity` ???

Comment: [`...` is not an operator!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508) (didn't even know we had a tag for that :( )

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is because the arguments-list specified by `(...[])` is the empty list of arguments -- i.e., you are doing `Math.min()` with no arguments.

The [EMCAScript spec for `Math.min` states](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-math.min):

> If no arguments are given, the result is +∞.

(And, unsurprisingly, it has [a similar statement for `Math.max`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-math.max).)